# How to save a captcha image, made with GD as a jpeg file?

Tags: php, image, gd

I wrote some codes to make a captcha code using GD in PHP. Everything is OK but when I right-click on the image which is showing the captcha code (to save it as image), file name on the window that opens for saving the file is `captch_add.php`; instead of that, I want it to be captcha.jpeg to save.

I have 3 files.

1. Captcha.php => a class for making the captcha image

   ```
     <?php

    class Captcha{
        protected string $font="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/acme/v17/RrQfboBx-C5_bx0.ttf";
        protected int $captchaLen=6;
        protected int $fontSize=25;
        public  function captchaControl($width,$height,$fontSize=null,$length=null,$fontFile=null){
            $fontFile= $fontFile ?? $this->font;
            $length=$length ?? $this->captchaLen;
            $fontSize=$fontSize ?? $this->fontSize;
            if (filter_var($fontFile,FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
                $font = file_get_contents($fontFile);
                file_put_contents("font.ttf", $font);
            }
            $captcha_code=strtoupper(substr(sha1(random_bytes(64)),rand(1,25),$length));
            $image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

            imageantialias($image, true);
            imagealphablending($image,true);
            $colors = [];

            $red = rand(125, 175);
            $green = rand(125, 175);
            $blue = rand(125, 175);
            $black = imagecolorallocate($image, 35, 35, 35);
            $white = imagecolorallocate($image, 220, 220, 220);
            $textColors = [$black, $white];
            for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
                $colors[] = imagecolorallocate($image, $red - 20*$i, $green - 20*$i, $blue - 20*$i);
            }

            imagefill($image, 0, 0, $colors[0]);

            for($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++) {
                imagesetthickness($image, rand(2, 10));
                $rect_color = $colors[rand(1, 4)];
                imagerectangle($image, rand(-10, $width), rand(-10, $width), rand(-10, $width), 10, $rect_color);
            }
            $initial = 15;
            $letter_space = $fontSize-10;
            $randPosition=rand($initial,$width-($letter_space*$length));
            for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                imagettftext($image, $fontSize, rand(-15, 15), $randPosition + $i*$letter_space, rand($height/2-5,$height/2+10), $textColors[rand(0, 1)], __DIR__."/font.ttf", $captcha_code[$i]);
            }

            imagejpeg($image);
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['img_number'] = $captcha_code;
            imagedestroy($image);

        }
    }
   ```
2. captcha_add.php => a file for showing the image

   ```
    <?php
    require_once "Captcha.php";
    @ob_get_level();
    header("content-type:image/jpeg");
    @ob_end_clean();
    $captcha=new Captcha();
    $captcha->captchaControl(200,50);
   ```
3. index.php => main file

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <form class="mx-auto">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group ">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Enter the Captcha</label>
                <div class="d-flex">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control mr-2" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="captcha">
                    <img src="captcha_add.php" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried this:

```
imagejpeg($image,"captcha.jpeg",100);
```

In this case if I put this JPEG file as src:

```
<img src="captcha.jpeg" alt="">
```

Then with each reload of the page, the image wont change.
I don't know what should I do.

Comment: Why not use a PHP file in the `src`, to avoid writing files? If there were multiple users on your site, each of them would generate it's own version of `captcha.jpeg` and overwrite the version of another user

Comment: If I want to use PHP file in src then because I mentioned that it has to save in captcha.jpeg it'll show me nothing, other wise if I don't mention that it has to save in captcha.jpeg again I'll have that problem which I said in the question.

Comment: Why do you need to save the file on each request? If the URL should be a different one, use a rewrite rule

Comment: It was just a way to see if my problem would be solved. My problem is that the browser is looking at to the captcha as an image but with `.php` extension. I want the captcha to be image with real images extensions like `.jpeg` .

Comment: Then use a rewrite rule. File extensions do not define how the file is handled, headers do